# Xcode Autolayout - make subviews small in landscape view

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have this following views in my storyboard. portrait version works fine without any problem. but i want to make `Profile Image` smaller in landscape view. then bottom item gets the space in screen. do i need to do the coding other than AutoLayout

Portrait Mode

[image]

Landscape Mode

[image]

StoryBoard View

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do any code. Its quite straight forward. Have you given hight constraint to profile image? Are you using size classes?

Comment: @Irfan only gave top and bottom constraints only. if i give left and right image get disappeared

Comment: It's disappearing because when you update the frame it's setting the Width to 0. Or your Height constraint is wrong and it's squashing it to make the Height 0.

Comment: Brother you just have to add a constraint for height and make it proportional to superview height 0.4, 0.3 whatever as per your requirement, autolayouts with size classes is now really straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

Boy here are the steps to follow,

- Add Height, Width Constrainsts to UIImageView as mentioned in below pic

[image]

[image]

- You added height, widths constrainsts succesfully, now we will add size classes for all iphones in landscape view. check the pic for size classes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Now you are done with adding size classes for height constraint, do same steps for width constraints (this is your home work).
- Check output in below pics

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey u created a project to help him hats off... :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not think of the orientation as "Landscape" anymore. It's best to think of it as Vertical: Compact, Height: Compact, which is essentially landscape for all iPhones except the 6+.

At the bottom of Storyboard you will see a small menu that looks like this [image: layout menu for size classes on Xcode Storyboard]

Select the size class you want. If you don't know them well enough, Xcode tells you what each one is for.

Control drag from the `UIImageView` to the main `UIView` and select "Equal Widths" and command click to "Equal Heights" too.

Click on your `UIImageView`. In the "Utilities" Inspector Bar area (right panel), click on the "Ruler" icon, and you will see the constraints for the `UIImageView`.

Adjust the "Equal Heights" and "Equal Widths" constraints to be a percentage of the view. You might have to tweak it to your liking.

You do not need anything more than `Autolayout` to do this. Do not set the frame directly in `viewWillTransitionToSize:coordinator:` - you're basically hard-coding the frame size by doing that and you'll have to do a lot of checking for `UITraitCollection` for each size class to set the frame for each.

Answer (score 1):

Let the constraints be `IBOutlet` property, and adjust them in portrait or landscape modes.
You can set up those `IBOutlet` properties in the storyboard of Xcode.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageHeightConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageWidthConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonBottomConstraint;
// Other constraints ....


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
       // Portrait mode
       self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = ooo;
       // Adjust other constraints
       // ....
    } else {
       // Landscape mode
       self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = xxx;
       // Adjust other constraints
       // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the frame manually for both the orientations using the If-else condition.

example:

```
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait) 
{
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 800);


            self.tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 764,510);

        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
        {
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1300, 370);
            self.tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1300, 370);
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        }
```